# CRUD in ASP.NET MVC 1 vs MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am doing [this tutorial][1] over at www.asp.net. It is written for ASP.NET MVC 1. Although most of the stuff works for MVC 3, I do have a question regarding this code:

**ASP.NET MVC 1.0 (straight from the tutorial)**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")] Contact contactToCreate)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View();

    try
    {
        _entities.AddToContactSet(contactToCreate);
        _entities.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**ASP.NET MVC 3 (default Create action generated by MVC 3 Project, except my _entities object)**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                _entities.AddToContacts(collection); // synax error
                _entities.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

So my question is why do we pass `Contact contactToCreate` in the first case, but `FormCollection collection` in the second?

I could easily change argument in the second example to just Contact `Contact contactToCreate`, but I am curious as to what is this `FormCollection collection` stuff? Why did MVC 3 generate it for us? If it's possible to use **FormCollection** instead, how would the modified example look like?
[1]: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/iteration-1-create-the-application-cs

Comment: That does seem like a step backwards...My guess is that you can still use the strongly-typed version if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormCollection` is the values entered by the user and `Contact` is the enderlying entity that you are creating.

Remember that this method is essentially called directly by the user as the result of a HTTP post and its bad practice to be blindly accepting user input without validating it.  This and the fact that in real-world scenarios the values available to you in a HTTP post request don't exactly match up to your data entity properties is probably the reason why its probably a good idea to accept a `FormCollection` (or other abstracted input representing your form values) rather than directly accepting an entity in your database.

Personally my modified example would look a little like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
        var contactToCreate = validateAndCreateContact(collection);
        if (contactToCreate != null)
        {
            _entities.AddToContacts(collection);
            _entities.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Logic to display error on the view goes here, e.g.
        base.ViewData["Exception"] = ex;
    }
    return View();
}

private Contact validateAndCreateContact(FormCollection collection)
{
    // Your implementation here
}
```

The `validateAndCreateContact` should validate user input and return a suitable `Contact` object if the input is all OK.  If not it should return `null` and handle displaying a suitable error to the user (for example by setting properties on the `ViewData`).

Comment: (Nitpick), don't use `ViewData` to hold onto errors. Use `ModelState.AddError` before returning the View.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd stick with your MVC1 example -- no need to go back into loosey goosey key value collection land.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use FormCollection. [This great tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg685494.aspx) from Microsoft explains that you should change the created signature to use your Model. The reason it uses FormCollection is because the Model isn't specified when it generates the scaffolding code. Hope this helps.

> The second Create method is of more interest. This is the one that will be called when the Create view posts back. By default, the template told this Create method to expect a FormCollection to be passed in as a parameter.
>
> Because the Create view was created as a strongly-typed view, it will be able to pass back a strongly typed Blog object. This means you can change that signature so that the method receives a Blog type.  That will simplify the task of adding the new blog to the BlogModelContainer and saving it back to the database using Entity Framework code.